# Reducing the number of registers by using 32bit rather than 64bit

Tags: cuda

I am on compute 3.5 using GTX Titan. On Windows 8 64bit and CUDA 5 64bit.

As I am not exceeding 3 GB of global memory usage and all my variables are using 32bit or below, I am wondering whether using 32bit bit kernel would, reduce the number of register usage, given that pointers now will be u32.

> 1. Does a 64bit pointer occupy two registers?
> 2. Anybody tried to reduce the number of registers by compiling the kernel to 32bit? (I didn't try this as I am assuming I need to install
>      the 32bit version of CUDA).

Comment: On win7 64 bit cuda 5, I can build a 32 bit app or a 64 bit app, by changing a few project settings.  For 64 bit cuda 5, passing the `-m32` flag to the compiler will tell it to [build 32 bit device code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sixtyfour-bit-compatibility).  This change and other changes needed are handled when I change  project type from `x64` to `Win32`.  Yes, 64 bit values occupy two (32-bit) registers.

Comment: Is not this an answer more than a comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. On win7 64 bit cuda 5, I can build a 32 bit app or a 64 bit app, by
   changing a few project settings:

   - For 64 bit cuda 5, passing the -m32 flag to the compiler will tell it
     to [build 32 bit device

     code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#sixtyfour-bit-compatibility).
   - This change and other changes needed are handled when I change
     project type from `x64` to `Win32`.

`  2. Yes, 64 bit values occupy two (32-bit) registers.